# Blob has no text() function in Safari 14 on iOS

Tags: blob, mobile-safari, wkwebview

I'm using a WKWebView on iOS to render an SVG. The SVG is created like this simplified example in a third-party library:

```js
var svgBlob = new Blob(['<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n' + '<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>'], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
```

My code then tries to obtain the raw SVG text like this:

```js
var svgText = await svgBlob.text();
```

On Safari 15 and higher, everything works as expected—-the SVG data is returned—-but on Safari 14, I get the error `svgBlob.text()` is not a function. Upon further inspection, `svgBlob` is in fact a blob, has a size, a type, and a `slice` function, but no other properties. The `text` property/function doesn't even exist.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) indicates that this API has existed on Safari on iOS since v14, and there are no caveats listed.

Is there some sort of trick to making this work?